# Call the REST API url using asp.net / JQuery Ajax

Tags: c#, rest, api

I have to call a REST url for example : https://{baseurl}/employees/taxvalidation/. The Request type is JSON, but I'am always get the error Alert. I can't figure out what is the wrong in my code. I am using JQuery

The Supported HTTP Method is : PUT (HTTP PUT with correct request needs to be made) and also i need to pass a API key: XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX as  request Header.

I have just have two mandatory fields in web page Employee name and Employee Tax.
I have tried the below using JQuery Ajax call.

Request Body Sample:

```
 "name": "Company XYZ",  /* mandatory */
 "TAX": "*********",  /* mandatory */
 "taxType": "U", /* Could be E, S, or U */
 "address": "2501 Boilermaker road", /* optional */
 "citystatezip":"Lapalma ca 76567", /* optional */
 "country": "US", //optional
 "checks" : "DT",`enter code here`
 "details": "DT"`enter code here` //optional

$(function() {
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function() {
        alert("Hi JQuery");
        var URL = "https://api.dev.amx-city.com/tesmdm/dev/tesmdm/empcatalog/partners/taxvalidation/";        
        $.ajax({
            url: URL,
            headers : {
                'AMX-API-KEY': '487b9474-27a6-4d21-8eda-c3a2a14e4ebe'
            },
            type: 'POST',    
            data: {
                name: 'Employeename',
                tin: '79847324987',
                tinType: 'U'
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(result) {
                alert(result);
            },
            error: function (restul) {
                alert(result);
        }
        });
});
});
```

when i try to hit the button the debugging is stopped till Alert, after that i don't see the URL is hitting. Let me know if i am doing any wrong?

Comment: What have you tried so far, what errors are you getting?

Comment: Hi, I have not tired any so far, i just want to know sampel codes similar to my requirement.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a freelancing service. Please submit a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) otherwise we cannot help you.

Comment: Hi, i understood. I just tried using JQuery and url is not hitting using ajax call. let me know what i am doing wrong.

Comment: You said the supported method is PUT, but you’re using POST in your code. Try changing to PUT..

Comment: I am getting error as  ---> "{ "httpCode":"405", "httpMessage":"Method Not Allowed", "moreInformation":"The method is not allowed for the requested URL" }"

Comment: In your ajax request, try changing the type to PUT e.g. `type: 'PUT',`

Comment: I tried using 'PUT' also, but same error

Comment: Are you able to show the server controller action method i.e. the PUT handler?

Comment: i used traditional Html button with JQuery ajax methods. I am getting the Alert, i am not sure whether i am missing any. this is the REST url with Http Header is 'PUT' that is what i got the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get the response now. Below is the working script

```
$.ajax({
    url: URL,
    type: "PUT",
    headers: {
        'AXT-API-KEY': '48776474-26a6-4d21-8eda-c3a2a14e4ebe'
    },
    data: JSON.stringify({"name": "SupplierName, LLC","tin": "522323454","tinType": "U","checks": "DT"
    }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
       alert(result);
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
       alert(xhr);
       alert(thrownError);
    }
});
```

Comment: All, when i try to use the same code in one of my ASP.NET MVC using JQuery ajax call, i am getting Response as :  {"httpCode":"401", "httpMessage":"Unauthorized", "moreInformation":"Invalid client id or secret." }, Can any one help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

It worked when i use the key in beforeSend function. But i am not sure the difference.

beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("AXT-API-KEY': '48776474-26a6-4d21-8eda-c3a2a14e4ebe");